# d3 error: DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting an error with the following code.

```js
const div = d3.select('div');

const t = d3.timer((e) => {
  const outerOneData = d3.range(0,5);
  const outerTwoData = d3.range(0,3);
  
  const outerOne = div.selectAll('div');

  
  outerOne.exit().remove();
  
  outerOne.data(outerOneData)
    .join('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id',(_,i)=>`outer${i}`);
    
 const outerTwo = outerOne.selectAll('div');  
  
   outerTwo.exit().remove();
  
  outerTwo.data(outerTwoData)
    .join('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id',(_,i)=>`outerTwo${i}`);
  
  
  if (e > 200) t.stop();
}, 150);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>   
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

But not with the following (when I am doing only one level).

```js
const div = d3.select('div');

const t = d3.timer((e) => {
  const outerOneData = d3.range(0,5);
  const outerTwoData = d3.range(0,3);
  
  const outerOne = div.selectAll('div');

  
  outerOne.exit().remove();
  
  outerOne.data(outerOneData)
    .join('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id',(_,i)=>`outer${i}`);
    
 /*const outerTwo = outerOne.selectAll('div');  
  
   outerTwo.exit().remove();
  
  outerTwo.data(outerTwoData)
    .join('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id',(_,i)=>`outerTwo${i}`);*/
  
  
  if (e > 200) t.stop();
}, 150);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>   
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

I intend d3 to give me following data-bound structure in DOM

```
└── doc
    ├── <div id='viz'>
    │   └── <div id='outer0'>
    │       ├── <div id='inner0'>
    │       ├── <div id='inner1'>
    │       └── <div id='inner2'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the hierarchy and the selection mechanism you're using with D3.

In your first example, after you bind data to outerOne and create div elements, you immediately try to select div elements inside them and bind data to outerTwo. This operation is inherently flawed because of how D3 works:

1. You select all divs inside div.
2. You bind data and append child divs for outerOne.
3. You then immediately try to select all divs inside outerOne (which would effectively reselect outerOne divs) and bind another set of data, which conflicts with the previous data binding.

This results in D3 attempting to append child divs (outerTwo) to themselves or their direct parents (outerOne), leading to the DOMException error.

To fix the first example:

1. Create a clear distinction between your primary div (outerOne) and the child div (outerTwo).
2. Avoid using generic selectors that might overlap in hierarchy. Instead, use class names or other attributes to narrow down the selection to the intended elements.

Here's a corrected version

```
const div = d3.select('#viz');

const t = d3.timer((e) => {
    const outerOneData = d3.range(0, 5);
    const outerTwoData = d3.range(0, 3);

    // Bind outerOneData to top-level divs
    const outerOne = div.selectAll('.outerOne').data(outerOneData);

    // Create/Update/Remove top-level divs
    outerOne
        .join('div')
        .classed('outerOne', true)  // Assign a class to distinguish them
        .attr('id', (_, i) => `outer${i}`)
        .selectAll('.outerTwo')    // Now select child divs inside each outerOne div
        .data(() => outerTwoData)  // Bind outerTwoData to child divs
        .join('div')
        .classed('outerTwo', true) // Assign a class to distinguish them
        .attr('id', (_, i) => `outerTwo${i}`);

    // Remove divs no longer in the data
    outerOne.exit().remove();

    if (e > 200) t.stop();
}, 150);
```

Comment: I have checked this with svg <g>element as well by replacing `divOuter>divInner` with `gOuter>gInner` and it stands out. With this selection, I am able to append the children to the parent which is of the same kind. Thanks for this.